# AspNet core default content type for Json

Tags: asp.net-core

Is there a way to retrieve the default content type for json used within aspnet core mvc?

I know that for json the following content type is used: "application/json; charset=utf-8". I would like to access this default from within a controller or service. I need this for something and I don't want to have it hardcoded somewhere.